# How to access a specific value from an Array (?) in Python

Tags: python, arrays, variables

this is probably a very simple question but I still can't figure out how to solve it.
First of all I'm not entirely sure if the result is stored in an Array (hence the question mark). However, I do have a variable called "result" which has the following output:

```
print(result)
{'memberId': '66034069761', 'name': 'Michael'}
```

Now I want to create a new variable e.g. "member" and assign the name of "result" to it.

So it basically should look like this:

```
print(member)
Michael
```

How do I do that? :|
 Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `result` is a `dict` object. You can read about Python dictionaries [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Is this a `json` or `dict` ?

Comment: I don't know unfortunately @Iron Fist

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks to @blorgon I found out it's not an array but a dictionary.

I could simply do the following:
member = result["name"]

Thanks!!!